# How to display number of items in a folder - Bash

Tags: bash

When I execute the `ls -l -h` command, I get an output as show by the image below.
[image]

How can the number of the items in a folder be included in the output?

**Update**
The current output looks like this

```
total 41M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      41M Dec 20 09:56 completed_projects.bson
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      213 Dec 20 09:57 completed_projects.metadata.json
drwxrwxr-x 2 adipster adipster 4.0K Jun 16 13:22 contents
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adipster adipster   13 Jun 16 13:20 file.py
drwxrwxr-x 4 adipster adipster 4.0K Jun 16 13:22 folder
drwxrwxr-x 2 adipster adipster 4.0K Jun 16 13:21 items
```

But I'll like to have another column indicating the number of items in a folder like this

```
total 41M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      41M Dec 20 09:56 completed_projects.bson
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      213 Dec 20 09:57 completed_projects.metadata.json
drwxrwxr-x 2 adipster adipster 4.0K Jun 16 13:22 contents  235
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adipster adipster   13 Jun 16 13:20 file.py  
drwxrwxr-x 4 adipster adipster 4.0K Jun 16 13:22 folder  19
drwxrwxr-x 2 adipster adipster 4.0K Jun 16 13:21 items  5
```

where the numbers at the extreme right represents the number of items in a folder

Comment: What about running `ls | wc -l`?

Comment: @choroba thanks for your response but `ls | wc -l` will display the number of items in a folder but I'll like that it be included as one of the columns in the output of the `ls` command.

Comment: @Cels see my answer does it look like something you want?

Comment: Hen you copy/paste the `~/dump` as text, it will be a lot easier to show what output you want. Do you want the nr of files in the current dir or from the subdirs? Plain file count 1 like `... file.py   1` and for subdir contents with 832 files something like `... contents 832`.

Comment: @WalterA That's exactly what I need

Comment: Replace image with its text and add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
echo -n "Number of files in folder is: " && ls | wc -l && ls -l
```

ouptut should be something like this:

```
umber of files in folder is: 3
Total 279K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user users 19K Jun 16 00:17 a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user users 5K Jun 16 00:17 b
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user users 255K Jun 16 00:17 c
```

You can omit `echo` statement, just as a note `-n` is *no new line* flag.

Comment: Your answer was not exactly what I wanted but it helped me figure out a temporal solution. I want that for each directory on the listed output, it should include the number of items in that directory. +1 anyways. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sed` has an option to execute the constructed replacement with `/e`.
We only count subdirs, looking at the first character

```
ls -l | sed -r 's/d(.*) ([^ ]*)/printf "d%s %-20s%s\n" "\1" \2 $(ls \2| wc -l)/e'
```

EDIT: Solution for directories with spaces in their name.

Parsing `ls` should be avoided. When you try to fix above cmmand for directory names with spaces, you might try

```
# Don't do this
ls -l | sed -r 's/d(.{,48}) (.*)/printf "d%s %-20s%s\n" "\1" "\2" $(ls "\2"| wc -l)/e'
```

It is time to write a script. Perhaps with `find` or something like

```
#/bin/bash
for i in *; do
   printf "%-70s %s\n" "$(/bin/ls -ld "$i")" "$(/bin/ls -d "$i"/* 2>/dev/null| wc -l)"
done
```

The `wc` in the subdir will count wrong when filenames have newlines.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Walter A. The only issue with this is that it fails when a folder contain spaces. But I'll see if I can make it work perfectly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ls() { command ls "$@" | tee >(echo "$(wc -l) items"); }
```

That uses an output process substitution to run the little "echo" script on its stdin while also displaying stdin (thanks to `tee`). This way, you don't have to run `ls` twice.

Usual caveat: output will be incorrect when there's a file with a newline in the name.

Comment: I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('` after running the command

Comment: @Cels: This might help: replace `ls()` with `function ls`.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of error where you're not actually using bash, or perhaps your bash version is too old. What is your bash version?